# Unity: How to roll back to the previous Scene after adding a canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, scene

I should be a very newbie question, but I really didn't get an answer after googling a lot of time...
Following a book guide, I create a mobile game and below it is the game's scene.

[image]

And then I add a canvas in order to add game level and score text, then my scene became as below white and black mode.

[image]

So my question is that how I can switch to my previous scene since I still need to edit the GameObject in the scene like changing their positions.

Comment: ther canvas is much higher than the sprites in the scene, zoom in the bottom left corner of the canvas, there they are

Comment: you can select any sprite and press f twice also

Comment: Since this has nothing to do with programming this question is off topic here anyway. Next time this should go to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Configure your editor so that you can see the scene view and the game view at the same time.  Then drag UI elements around your canvas. You will understand what is going on then.  Unity just has this weird way of showing you the screen space overlay canvas as this HUGE box next to your world space.

Comment: @Lestat, Alex Myers, thanks for your guys comment, I get it now:)
And derHugo, good to know there is a game specific community, I will join it since I'm interest in gaming on programming.

Comment: For unity specific questions you can post on https://forum.unity.com/

Answer (score 0):

you are still in the same scene. just looking a different way or zoomed way out. maybe both. on the left hand side where all your items are listed double click one(that you want to locate), it will find and zoom in on that object, from there you should be able to see your other objects as well

the canvas is a UI object and is displayed to your camera, it dosnt need to be aligned, its just massize, but when you play your game it will appear right. have you tried hitting play? otherwise if you really need to go back `ctrl-z` to your hearts content